# How to build LibGDX from source?

Tags: java, android, c++, ant, libgdx

I am trying hard to build LibGDX from sources (with ANT). I have some minor changes in the native code. I only need compilation for Android.

Theoretically, I've finally managed to compile my C++ files, by switching to Ubuntu (on Windows ANT did not even try to compile). I made some minor changes in `.java` files. I then ran main `Build.xml`  - the one that builds the `jar`s, and open resultant `gdx-setup.jar`. Everything installed fine, new projects for eclipse were created.

But my changes were not applied. Auto-completion did not see anything. I also couldn't run the app - java complained, that it couldn't find `MyGameClass`, even if it was clearly in the `core` project. Funny thing is, the same exception will come up even when I do not modify anything.

This makes me think, that despite my two days' effort, I still do everything wrong. How should I do it?

Comment: gdx-setup (just like gradle) will download the latest prebuild version, not your custom build. Instead you'll need to work from source, see https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Running-demos-%26-tests

Comment: @Xoppa, thanks I'll look into it right away. I was able to create libGDX project with my internet disconnected, though :/

Comment: @Xoppa Importing projects into Eclipse gives me 100 errors, maybe something is wrong with the current source release?

Comment: I do: git pull; ant -f fetch.xml ; ant and it works.

Comment: It's normal to get errors, for example because of a wrong jre or android api. With that in mind, the errors are pretty self-explanatory and should be easy to fix. Don't forget to refresh and clean all when needed.